# How to create a custom asset-attributes.hbs for each new artifact for the STORE?

Tags: wso2, wso2-governance-registry

Im using WSO2 Governance Registry 5.2.0.

When I create a new artifact type, it containt a lot of new fields (You create and define this XML in the CARBON ADMIN CONSOLE). So in the PUBLISHER you can see the new fields, create and consult a new item of the artifact.

But the problem is in the STORE, I cannot see the this new fields. So in order to do this, I made the custom fields available by modifying 
*GREG_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/store/extensions/app/greg-store-defaults/themes/store/partials/asset-attributes.hbs* file. Thanks to [Malintha's Blog](http://blog.malintha.org/wso2-governance-registry-adding-custom-artifacts/),

This is perhaps an answer, but it will get much worse if for each artifact I have to edit the file to add the fields, editing this file will get a lot worse over the time...

So my question is: Is there a way to create a custom theme (*.hbs, etc) for each new artifact I create?

THANKS!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I understand your in the development phase of the project that you have to create registry extensions(RXTs) and showing up the data in G-Reg Store. As far as I know there is no easy dynamic way that you can do this, either you have to extend the default hbs files. Like you have done using Malintha's blog. This is okay if there is a minor change to be done, However this is not the recommended way because if there is a migration to do such as moving to all new [WSO2 G-Reg 5.3.0](http://wso2.com/products/governance-registry/) you might face lot of trouble if you updated the out of the box files in G-Reg 5.2.0, Therefore I suggest you to write asset extensions(`GREG_HOME/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/store/extensions/assets`) for each and every rxt that you are going to introduce. There is plenty of blog posts that can help you.

**Please find the below list of blog posts(I will update the list if I found any).**

1. [Adding a New Asset Type](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ES100/Adding+a+New+Asset+Type)
2. [How to view the json payload sent to the Store UI in GREG 5.1.0](http://niranjankaru.blogspot.com/2016/02/how-to-view-json-payload-sent-to-store.html)
3. [How to extend an asset's store view in WSO2 GREG 5.1.0](http://niranjankaru.blogspot.com/2016/02/how-to-extend-assets-store-view-in-wso2.html)
4. [WSO2GREG-5.2.0- WRITING EXTENSION TO REPLICATE MORE ARTIFACT
   METADATA IN STORE](http://asadistechspace.blogspot.com/2016/04/wso2greg-520-writing-extension-to.html#.V6_iE5N95E8)
5. [Overriding default "look and feel" of GREG - 5.3.0](http://chanaka3d.blogspot.com/2016/07/overriding-defalut-look-and-feel-of.html)

Note:

- There is no much difference between 5.1.0 and 5.2.0.(5.2.0 is more stable)
- You can start(learn) creating a new extension by simply extending restservice.rxt and the relevant asset extension(GREG_HOME/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/store/extensions/assets/restservice), I prefer you to use [this](http://asadistechspace.blogspot.com/2016/04/wso2greg-520-writing-extension-to.html#.V6_iE5N95E8) blog post and start from there.
- If there is a lot of development to be done I prefer you to seek help from WSO2 experts from [they're official portal](http://wso2.com/contact/), if not you can always stick to stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! At least extending the default hbs files works for me! I now i understand how to configure it by each artifacts! Thanks for the explanation and links!

Comment: I'm happy if my answer helps you. Let me know if you want more clarifications.