# Can APIs be added as a custom asset in the G-reg?

Tags: api, wsdl, wso2, wso2-governance-registry

Just like WS-Policies, Swagger , WSDLs, WADLs etc.Can APIs be added as a custom asset in the G-reg?

Comment: Is it possible to improve you question by proving a sample API content? Then we can provide you a correct answer. Basically, G-Reg can store any text based artifact type out of the box.

Comment: @vanya-kashyap if you have RXT based representation for the API assets, you can directly deploy into G-Reg.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand you need to introduce a new content type artifact(*WSDL, WADL, Policy and Schemas are known as content type artifacts*) to G-Reg. To upload such artifact programmatically you need to write some custom code which is called handlers and extensions,

**Handlers**

Please find this [blog post](http://sencs.blogspot.com/2016/04/how-to-develop-governance-registry.html) which explains a basic handler for your requirement. Other than that please refer below sample media type handlers available in G-Reg(carbon-registry)

[WSDLMediaTypeHandler.java](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-registry/blob/7a7ef5b9998bd46f5be3fd2684951991bfc51386/components/registry/org.wso2.carbon.registry.extensions/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/registry/extensions/handlers/WSDLMediaTypeHandler.java)

[SwaggerMediaTypeHandler.java](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-registry/blob/7a7ef5b9998bd46f5be3fd2684951991bfc51386/components/registry/org.wso2.carbon.registry.extensions/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/registry/extensions/handlers/SwaggerMediaTypeHandler.java)

[WADLMediaTypeHandler.java](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-registry/blob/7a7ef5b9998bd46f5be3fd2684951991bfc51386/components/registry/org.wso2.carbon.registry.extensions/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/registry/extensions/handlers/WADLMediaTypeHandler.java)

**GC Eextensions**

If you're introducing a content type artifact it is must write a publisher and store extensions to get it work in pub/store. However, users can upload such artifacts in admin/mgt console just by deploying the handler correctly.

Please find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38921784/how-to-create-a-custom-asset-attributes-hbs-for-each-new-artifact-for-the-store/38938924#38938924) to get an idea of the extension creation.