# Add multiple Web Service Operations in WSO2 Governance Registry

Tags: wso2, wso2-governance-registry

I need to add new field to the Soap Service. This field can add unbounded operations (contain name, description, example xml).For example, is this possible?

[image: example]

In the Artifact Source i tried  inside a  but it is not possible and I cant see how to make something similar like the image.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new field which can add unbounded operations as displayed in the image attached through the below code segment. Hope this helps.

[image: Publisher create view]

```
    <table name="WebServiceOperations" columns="3" maxoccurs="unbounded">
    <subheading>
        <heading>Name</heading>
        <heading>Description</heading>
        <heading>XML</heading>
    </subheading>
    <field type="text">
        <name label="Name">name</name>
    </field>
    <field type="text-area">
        <name label="Description">description</name>
    </field>
    <field type="text-area">
        <name label="xml">xml</name>
    </field>
</table>
```

Note: If you want to get the exact view you have to create or update the GC extension points. For that please refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38921784/how-to-create-a-custom-asset-attributes-hbs-for-each-new-artifact-for-the-store/38938924#38938924).